# Stored Procedures SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure which lists all customers that have 7 days left on their membership.

```
CREATE PROC spGetMemReminder
AS
    SELECT users.fullname,
           membership.expiryDate
    FROM   membership
           INNER JOIN users
             ON membership.uid = users.uid
    WHERE  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), expiryDate, 105) =
           CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ( getdate() + 7 ), 105)
```

I would like to insert this list into another table automatically. How do I achieve this? any suggestions appreciated. Thanks

Comment: By automatically you mean on a schedule? If so what edition of SQL Server are you on? Also what is the need to materialize this resultset into another table at all?

Comment: I see no reason to use a stored procedure here, use a view instead.

Comment: I agree with tombom, I don't see why a stored procedure is needed here. A view would be much easier to deal with.

Comment: don't use convert() to compare dates like that. DATEDIFF() will be much faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the other suggestion is... don't write a stored procedure to insert into a temp table, because the data will always be changing.

Just write a view....... and have your "report" use/consume the view.

```
if exists (select * from sysobjects 
    where id = object_id('dbo.vwExpiringMemberships') and sysstat & 0xf = 2)
    drop VIEW dbo.vwExpiringMemberships

GO


/*
select * from dbo.vwExpiringMemberships
*/

CREATE VIEW dbo.vwExpiringMemberships AS  

    SELECT usr.fullname,
           mem.expiryDate
    FROM   dbo.Membership mem
           INNER JOIN dbo.Users usr
             ON mem.uid = usr.uid
    WHERE  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), expiryDate, 105) =
           CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ( getdate() + 7 ), 105) 


GO



GRANT  SELECT ,  UPDATE ,  INSERT ,  DELETE  ON  [dbo].[vwExpiringMemberships] TO public
GO
```

Comment: Remember, there are "Yes this was helpful" arrows....and there is a "Mark as Answer".  Not sure if you're new to stackoverflow, but this is proper etiquette.  Esp the "mark as answer" when your answer is answered, so it doesn't keep showing up in the "Filter by Unanswered" screens (for people responding to posted questions).

Comment: Since your new, I think a best practice is to preface your tables with the schema name.  Don't use "Select * from Employee", use "Select * from dbo.Employee".  I'm updating the view code in my answer.

Comment: A view is a "virtual table".....after you create the view, you can treat it as a real-table for Selecting.  Updating or Deleting from a view is a much longer topic.  But for selecting, "Select * from dbo.MyView" works like selecting from a table for most intents and purposes.

Comment: I was giving you the syntax of a View.  You should implement the DATEDIFF() suggestion suggested in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Snipped this:

```
SELECT * INTO #MyTempTable FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=    (local)\SQL2008;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
 'EXEC getBusinessLineHistory')
```

From this: [Insert results of a stored procedure into a temporary table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/how-to-select-into-temp-table-from-stored-procedure)

Comment: Or you can just `CREATE TABLE #T` then `INSERT ... EXEC` with no need for `OPENROWSET`

Answer (score 0):

```
Insert into YOUR_TABLE exec("spGetMemReminder")
```

Comment: I am using sql server 2005. I have created a job which runs the stored procedure every day. This list would then be inserted into another table, which is displayed when I login. This enables me to see users that will expire in 7 days.. How would I accomplish this using a view? I am relatively new to SQL. Thanks!